# FILTERED instead of the param itself in the console debug message

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm following the authentication example in the Phoenix book and I can't get the username/password to work during Login even though I'm sure they match previous registration/creation.
When trying to understand the problem I realised that I can't see the password in the console but instead I have:

```
Processing by FabASA.SessionController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"session" => %{"password" => "[FILTERED]", "username" => "lol"}}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
```

Why does `[FILTERED]` appear and how to see the password value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Phoenix filters out any parameters containing `password`. This is to prevent passwords from being printed to log files.

You can remove this default by passing an empty list to the `filter_parameters` config, probably in `config/dev/exs`.

```
config :phoenix, :filter_parameters, []
```

The documentation for this is in [`Phoenix.Logger`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/297f81c7154149a13f9b61f069f5cc1b43816f3d/lib/phoenix/logger.ex#L5-L17)